Quartiles in R using a Dataset
I am fairly new to programming in R, and I was trying to find the first and third quartiles for the column titled "rm" in the dataset Boston (which I've renamed to BSTN). I keep getting an error of xtfrm.data.frame(x) and I don't know what the problem is with it. I think I am just using the quantile function wrong, but I am unsure how to fix it.
Here is the source code that I'm having trouble figure out:
l = BSTN["rm"]
w = quantile(l, probs = 0.25, na.rm=FALSE)
z = quantile(l, probs=0.75, na.rm = FALSE)


I've tried using different versions of finding quartiles online, with (w = quantile(l, probs = c(.25, .5, .75), type=1)), but I run into the same error.

Try l = BSTN[["rm"]]. Using a single [ will return a data frame rather than a vector of values.

Please read about how to make a great R reproducible example and update your question accordingly. Include a sample of your data by pasting the output of dput(<your data frame>) into your post or dput(head(<your data frame>)) if you have a large data frame. If you cannot post your data, then post code for creating representative data. Do not post images of code and/or data. You will get better and more exact help if you post a reproducible example.

Data
BSTN <- MASS::Boston

BSTN["rm"] selects a column in the data.frame BSTN and keeps the data frame structure
class(BSTN["rm"])
[1] "data.frame"

whereas e.g.
class(BSTN[,"rm"]) # comma, selecting by column
[1] "numeric"

returns a vector, which works as expected with quantile.
Note that a tibble::tibble also needs drop=TRUE or a unlist to cast a vector! Thanks @LMc!
quantile(BSTN[,"rm", drop=T])
    0%    25%    50%    75%   100% 
3.5610 5.8855 6.2085 6.6235 8.7800 

or using $
quantile(BSTN$rm)
    0%    25%    50%    75%   100% 
3.5610 5.8855 6.2085 6.6235 8.7800

Selecting the desired quants (since the defaults are 0, 25, 50, 75 and 100)
quantile(BSTN$rm)[c(2,4)]
   25%    75% 
5.8855 6.6235

